# Does "error-first-callback" necessary mean a two-parameter function for doing something with that callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Writing a Node app, I've been asked to use the [error first callback](http://thenodeway.io/posts/understanding-error-first-callbacks/) pattern.

The pattern dictates that the first parameter to the callback will be an error function, and the second parameter will be the response data, as is demonstrated  with the callback to the fs.readFile function:

```
fs.readFile('/foo.txt', function(err, data) {
  // TODO: Error Handling Still Needed!
  console.log(data);
});
```

However, the text itself does not say anything about the function that accepts the callback - here readFile.

Is there a best-practice about such a function? For example, I'm being told that it should only take two parameters, the second being the callback, as is the case in the example above. Is this right? Or is it acceptable to have any number of parameters? Should the callback be last? What are the reasons for such best practice, if it exists?

Comment: I hate the phrase "best practice", as generally what you're dealing with instead is the design principles that your app uses. I would assume the pattern only refers to the callback, and that the function that accepts the callback can have as many arguments as needed, as long as the callback is last and follows the pattern.

Comment: No; your function should take as many parameters as it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minor correction to your question --> The first parameter to the callback is an error object and NOT an error **function** as you have mentioned. Assuming its a typo.

About the function using the callback, there is no standard practice that I am aware of but to me it makes sense to have callback the last. I personally find it more readable. In my mind, callback is called later (or in the end), hence callback is the last parameter. Infact, if you see expressjs framework, the way route handling functions are defined, callbacks are called in the order they are defined.

for ex : app.get('someurl', cbfn1, cbfn2,.. cbfnN)
In above, callbacks are called in the order cbfn1, cbfn2... to cbfnN (assuming all the handlers call next()).

Answer (score 0):

The error first callback pattern just require that your function accept 2 parameters and the first is the error. And you are doing it right.

`err` is not a function. This is an object containing the information on the error. But i can be `null` (if you have no error).

You can handle it like this :

```
if(err) {
  console.log('Error !', err);
  return;
}
```